# (sed/awk) How to convert a field-delimited (like a csv) file into a txt with fixed-sized tab-delimited columns?

Tags: csv, sed, awk, format

I have something like a csv file in which the field delimiter is "@".

ID@Name@Surname@Age@Profession@Address

```
1254343123@John@Smith@24@Engineer@Washington
23@Alexander@Kristofferson-Brown@Economic Advisor@Kent
...
```

I want to convert it into something more human-readable as in:

```
1254343123    John        Smith                  24    Engineer            Washington
23            Alexander   Kristofferson-Brown    35    Economic Advisor    Kent
```

...where each column stars at a specific character.

I have tried something that takes advantage of the TAB-size value and adds several TABs to the field:

```
sed -e "{/@[^@]\{32,\}@/s/@\([^@]*\)@/\t\1\t/g};{/@[^@]\{24,31\}@/s/@\([^@]*\)@/\t\1\t/g};{/@[^@]\{16,23\}@/s/@\([^@]*\)@/\t\1\t\t/g};{/@[^@]\{8,15\}@/s/@\([^@]*\)@/\t\1\t\t/g};{/@[^@]\{2,7\}@/s/@\([^@]*\)@/\t\1\t\t\t/g}"
```

...which does not work in all cases.

Could somebody give me a hint as how to proceed?

PS: My intention is to use mainly sed (a one-liner) or if sed just doesn't cut it, awk is OK.

Comment: What you describe is not a CSV file. Anyway, can't you just replace all occurrences of '@' with ' '?

Comment: No. If I add spaces, there is no consistent column width. So it's not "human readable". I want a table-like format output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk -F@ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%-20s", $i};printf "\n"}' input.csv
```

#### Input

```
$ cat input.csv
1254343123@John@Smith@24@Engineer@Washington
23@Alexander@Kristofferson-Brown@35@Economic Advisor@Kent
```

#### Output

```
$ awk -F@ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%-20s", $i};printf "\n"}' input.csv
1254343123          John                Smith               24                  Engineer            Washington
23                  Alexander           Kristofferson-Brown 35                  Economic Advisor    Kent
```

If you want to make the field width (20 in the code above) a shell variable that can be passed in you do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

fldwth=20

awk -v fw=$fldwth -F@ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%-*s", fw,$i};printf "\n"}' input.csv
```

Comment: @manuel: To set per-column widths: `BEGIN { widthlist = "20 10 30 12 ..."; split(widthlist,widths," ") } { ... printf "%-*s", widths[i],$i ...`

Comment: I think the column command in larsmans' response is a better approach.

Comment: @pbh101 if you look at the comment I made to his answer over a year ago, you'll see I think so too :)

Answer (score 17):

BSD, Mac OS X and Linux have the `column` command for this:

```
column -t -s@
```

It produces spaces though, not tabs (and it should, because tabs are obsolete). Output:

```
1254343123  John       Smith                24  Engineer          Washington
23          Alexander  Kristofferson-Brown  35  Economic Advisor  Kent
```

Comment: A pity there is no column utility for use in the Windows Command shell - nothing to be found on GnuWin32

Comment: Tabs are only obsolete if you don't understand the difference between syntax and semantics.

Comment: you can always pipe through the utility "expand" to convert from spaces to tabs

Answer (score 1):

My solution for converting the excel default csv (comma delimited, text enclosed in double quotes) is the following awk script:

```
#!/bin/nawk -f
# Q&D to transform csv (with commas imbedded in quotes) to pipe (|)
# Usage: cma2pipe.awk <in.csv> > <out.csv>
# Note: Assumes that <in.csv> contains no ~ or |  
{#MAIN
  s=$0;c=0;f=0;        #reset varibles for a line
  while (c<length(s)){ #loop thru line
    c++;               #char counter
    a=substr(s,c,1);   #get current character
    if (a=="\"")f++;   #flag quote
    if (f%2==1&&a==",")#if inside pair of quotes, look for ","
      s= repl("~",c,s);#replace commas with ~
  }#end while c
  gsub(",","|",s);     #replace remaining , with |
  gsub("~",",",s);     #put commas back
  gsub("\"","",s);     #get rid of quotes
print s
}#end MAIN
function repl(r,n,t){  #replace single character in string
  s1=substr(t,1,n-1);  #get first part of string
  s2=substr(t,n+1);    #get last part of string
  return(s1 r s2);     #return changed string
}#end repl()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I adapted this to convert a space-separated, double-quote-encased TXT file into standard CSV: https://github.com/baisong/2018-Primary-Election-CA-SD-Results/blob/master/txt2csv.awk

Answer (score 0):

`awk -F@ '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}' file.csv > readable.txt`

Try this one using delimiter option for awk and printing columns by putting `\t` between each.

Comment: `awk '$0=gensub("@","\t","g")' file.csv` would be a better way to do this as it doesn't rely on the number of fields (also shorter script). But no matter how many tabs you add, the columns wont line up because you need to constrain the field widths, not just the inter-spacing.

Comment: `awk -F@ '{$1=$1; print}' OFS='\t' file.csv` (or `awk -F@ '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' file.csv`)